# Changing from HDD to SSD with my Airport Time Capsule

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, ssd, time-capsule, hdd

I will receive a new SSD very soon (Samsung 850 EVO 500gb).
My question is, will it be possible to transfer all my data from my HDD(I have a time machine backup of my computer on the airport time capsule).

Like lets say, i a) I insert my new ssd in the mac with absolutely nothing on and unplug the hdd. b) Booting my mac while holding (⌘-R or alt button???).

After that would it be possible to choose my network and choose the airport time capsule where i saved my time machine backup? Hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're on your Wi-Fi network, you should be able to do that, but if I were you I'd just buy a SATA-to-USB cable ($30 at Best Buy), install the SSD as usual, connect the HDD over USB, make a disk image of it with Disk Utility (in Recovery), and then install the image on the new drive. I did this when I upgraded my MacBook Pro to an SSD and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: So the macbook will be able to boot with a an SSD without anything on it at all? Thanks!

Comment: @user187685 It's not really OS X only Recovery, where OS X can be installed on a blank drive or cloned from the disk image of another (like your old HDD with all your files on it).

Comment: So i can acces Recovery and in recovery choose my time machine backup (image) and install it on my new ssd??

Comment: @user187685 Time Machine's doesn't really create disk images. It's backup software, which makes it easier to restore individual files, while a disk image is an EXACT copy of your drive. So nothing at all changes except for the drive itself. So, yes, you can restore a complete Time Machine backup to the new drive, but unless you have to (sudden drive failure or someone steals your Mac), restoring a disk image the best way.

Comment: All right. Thanks a lot for the help!! I have just ordered a SATA-to-USB cable and will do it the way you recommended. Good day to you.

Comment: @user187685 Glad I could help.